# Azure DevOps API using PATs returns HTML in my PHP curl call, Postman returns Json

Tags: php-curl

Trying to use the Azure APIs to build a web app that returns data from Azure Devops.

here is the API I'm calling: [https://dev.azure.com/{{organization-pica}}/{{project}}/_apis/test/Plans/14/suites/15/testcases?api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization-pica%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/test/Plans/14/suites/15/testcases?api-version=5.0)

POSTMAN: using basic authentication this works well and returns json result.

When I call this from PHP cURL it returns HTML?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Using the wrong URL. [https://dev.azure.com/{{organization-pica}}/{{project}}/_apis/test/Plans/4/suites/6?$expand={$expand}&api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization-pica%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/test/Plans/4/suites/6?$expand=%7B$expand%7D&api-version=5.0)

Comment: The link is broken.